TipKit Custom Style - popoverTip expands to the whole width of the screen
I am using the SwiftUI new TipKip popovertip modifier to add a tooltip on top of my view.
@ViewBuilder
func makeScheduledCardWithTooltip() -> some View {
    var shouldAddTooltip: Bool {
        //... not important for this context
        
        return true
    }
            
    if shouldAddTooltip, #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
        // Have to add here as the whole struct needs to support iOS 16
        let tip = LongPressAlarmTooltip()
        
        Rectangle()
            .popoverTip(tip, arrowEdge: .bottom)
    } else {
        Rectangle()
    }
}

Now the issue is, I want the tooltip to be smaller and not take the whole width, currently it expands all the way.
In the image below, if you see it goes edge to edge on the screen.

I made a function much simpler to follow. But for simplicity, imagine this function is in the ContentView and is in the body like:
var body: some View {
   makeScheduledCardWithTooltip()
}


Does the tip become smaller when you remove .popoverTip? From the image, I feel like the width of the tip is quite appropriate. Does making the text shorter decrease the tip width?

@Sweeper It does, but I very much prefer the text to remain the same length, but be on two lines and have a shorter width instead. If I remove the popoverTip() there would not be a tip at all.

How about making your own TipViewStyle? There, you can say something like .frame(width: 200) to make the width of the popover constant.

You can make your own TipViewStyle that has a fixed width.
Here is an example that shows the title and image of a tip, with a fixed width of 200pt.
struct NarrowStyle: TipViewStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: TipViewStyle.Configuration) -> some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            HStack {
                configuration.image
                configuration.title
            }
            Button {
                configuration.tip.invalidate(reason: .tipClosed)
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "xmark")
            }
            .tint(.gray.opacity(0.5))
        }
        .frame(width: 200)
        .padding()
    }
}

Usage:
SomeView()
    .popoverTip(someTip, arrowEdge: .bottom)
    .tipViewStyle(NarrowStyle())

Note that if the tip view's height grows so large that it cannot fit, TipKit will ignore your preference of arrowEdge: .bottom and shows the tip view with a different arrow direction.

Without NarrowStyle:

With NarrowStyle


Tip view style, as far as I know and tested, works only for inline tips, not popover tips. Have you tested it on your end and it works? For me it does not make any visual changes with the popover tips.

@Amin I have added before & after images. What iOS version are you running?

I am using 17.0. If you add any foreground or background colors, fonts and etc, nothing changes(at least for me) but on the inline version I can see the changes reflect appropriately.

@Amin Well that explains. I'm using 17.4, and Apple probably made some changes between versions.
